XSL-FO static-content is overlapped by content from second page
I am creating a pdf file to show records from a database to users. And it happened the system we rely on uses this apache xml, and I have little to no idea of it.
The problem is we have a header with the company logo and it looks ok only on the first page. The second page table (when table is long enough) overlaps the logo, as shown below. I edited the area covered by the logo for privacy concerns. The first image is the first page, the second one is the second page where the table content continues.


I did not create the document, but is has a layout master set like this:
 <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first"
      page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="0mm"
      margin-bottom="15mm" margin-left="15mm" margin-right="15mm">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm" />
      <fo:region-before />
      <fo:region-after />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest"
      page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="0mm"
      margin-bottom="15mm" margin-left="15mm" margin-right="15mm">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm" />
      <fo:region-before />
      <fo:region-after />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="last"
      page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="0mm"
      margin-bottom="15mm" margin-left="15mm" margin-right="15mm">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="10mm" margin-bottom="20mm" />
      <fo:region-before />
      <fo:region-after />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="allPages">
      <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="only" master-reference="first" />
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first" master-reference="first" />
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="rest" master-reference="rest" />
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="last" master-reference="rest" />
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="only" master-reference="last" />
      </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

Then I have the flow element starting like this, with the logo of the company.
<fo:page-sequence initial-page-number="1" master-reference="allPages">
    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
      <fo:block-container height="50mm" width="190mm"
        position="absolute" top="7.5mm" right="-5mm">
        <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-collapse="separate" >
          <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="190mm" />
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="0pt">
                <fo:block text-align="right">
                  <fo:external-graphic
                    src="Company_logo.png"
                    content-height="25mm" content-width="120mm"
                    scaling="uniform" />
                </fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
      </fo:block-container>
    </fo:static-content>

I don't understand what is causing the overlapping. I tried adding a margin-top on some elements, but it doesn't work consistently on all the pages. Then I realized the region-body, region-after and region-before elements in the simple-page-master could make the trick, but I couldn't. I tried adding background-color attribute to region-body elements, but it had no effect, so I couldn't figure out how they are organized in this particular document.
I just need to prevent the overlapping in the second page. The content should start below the logo.

First thing to keep in mind is that all pages are set ahead of time, and content is flowed into it. If you content overflows the region-before, then it will overlap. Putting a fixed position block in a header/footer area is never a good idea.

Increase margin-top of the xsl:region-body of the 'rest' and 'last' fo:simple-page-master.
It seems that the content at the start of your document appears to the left of your logo and that it just happens that anything on the right side of the page is formatted following that and so avoids the logo.  The repeated table header spans the page width and so overwrites the logo.  Increasing the margin-top on the second and subsequent pages will put the table header below the logo.

Consider adding visible borders to the fo:region elements in fo:simple-page-masters, just for debugging. This would clearly show the overlap even on the first page . Then adjust margins and/or logo size as needed. Unless you are OK with wasting quite some space at the top of every page, you might want to have different geometry on first compared with rest, and maybe skip the logo on the rest entirely.
